# Have the same Java file name as the project name in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am learning Java using `intelliJ`, I am wondering how to configure the `IDE` so that the default `Java` file (`Main.java`) when creating a new project, can have the same name as the project name.

cheers

Comment: What type of project? I don't think Java projects come with any java files

Comment: In any case, can't you just rename the file to what you want it to be?

Comment: @jlars62 The whole point is that he wants to do that automatically...

Comment: @jlars62 it is a `Java` project with a `command line template`, I can manually change the file name and class name to be the same, but don't think it is convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great choice using intelliJ. I think you'll find that it'll pay off when you start doing Android development.

Here are the steps you'll want to follow to achieve what you want:

1. Open the IDE Settings, then go to File and Code Templates.
2. Go to the Templates tab.
3. Click the "add" button on the toolbar. Here you'll be able to specify everything you want.
4. Change the template name to be `${PROJECT_NAME}`
5. Apply changes and close out.

You're golden!

You can read more about this [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html).

I hope this helps. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll fix the answer.

Comment: it still did not change the `Main.java` to the project name, I am wondering what does the `code template` do to the coding.

Comment: Check this link out as well, from the same site: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/saving-projects-as-templates.html